# How can I create a JSON API for a database for AngularJS?

Tags: python, database, json, api, angularjs

I recently completed the Lynda.com tutorial for AngularJS, and they show an example in which they used a JSON file to filter and sort the "airport data". However near the end they replace the actual file with an API that calls the database and returns data in JSON format.

How do I do that part on the backend? How do I have a database with JSON APIs? What's the best place to start?

I have some experience with frameworks like Django for the backend, so ideally Python would be the language on the backend.

Comment: What language do you plan to use on the server side? PHP, Java, RubyOnRails, Javascript,  Python, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a REST API on the backend, which will work with a database and return responses in JSON.

For Django: http://tastypieapi.org/ http://django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Thanks. Does this means I need to use an ORM or a framework like Django to achieve this? Thats exactly what I need to know...how to I get the REST API Backend

Comment: thanks for shining some light into this. I am learning a lot in a short period of time and its easy to get lost in all the details. I didn't even realized Django wasn't already enabling a REST API on the backend. What resource do I have available if Im using Node and MongoDB?